# jQuery DatePicker minDate not working in Internet Explorer and Safari

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, cross-browser, datepicker

I thought I had [jQuery's Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) working fine, but then the client noticed that it's not working correctly in IE and Safari (5 or 6). Doh.

According to the Datepicker documentation you should:

> "Set the beginning and end dates as actual dates (new Date(2009, 1 - 1,
>   26))"

That's what I've done, and it works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox.

Here's an example of the code I'm using, and a [jsFiddle illustrating the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/sAe4z/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var startDate = "2013,5,1";
  var endDate  = "2013,7,1";

  function noSundays(date) {
    return [date.getDay() != 0, ''];
  }    

  function datepickerInit(startDate, endDate) {
    $( "#date" ).datepicker({
      inline: true,
      minDate: new Date(startDate),
      maxDate: new Date(endDate),
      beforeShowDay: noSundays,
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' 
    });
  }   

  datepickerInit(startDate, endDate);   

});
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: What version of jquery you using?

Comment: @Jordan You can see the issue for yourself in the jsFiddle I linked to. (1.9.1)

Comment: Just making sure you weren't using something different on the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use Date Object instead of String while defining the startDate and endDate. You can try following code:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {

  var startDate = new Date( 2013,5-1,1);
  var endDate  = new Date(2013,7-1,1);

  function noSundays(date) {
    return [date.getDay() != 0, ''];
  }    

  function datepickerInit(startDate, endDate) {

    $( "#date" ).datepicker({
      inline: true,
      minDate:startDate,
      maxDate: endDate,
      beforeShowDay: noSundays,
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' 
    });
  }   

datepickerInit(startDate, endDate);   

});
```

Comment: Any idea why this solves the problem of the OP's code not working in IE and Safari?